# weblogic & OHS: How forward one url to a different server

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, weblogic, oracle-http-server

I have an environment with Oracle WebLogic and OHS running.

In the mod_wl_ohs.conf I have following (beside config for other applications)

```
  <Location /application1>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WLLogFile /opt/logs/ application1.log
    Debug OFF
    WebLogicHost 127.0.0.1
    WebLogicPort 23666
  </Location>
```

This works fine the and the server listening to 23666 with the actual application1 application is handling the requests like “http://example.com/application1/*” .

Now I would like to redirect all requests for specific URL pattern to a different domain (not necessary on the same server), but continuing handling all requests others.
Redirect: `http://example.com/application1/MagicKeyword/*`
continue on: `http://example.com/application1/NotTheKeyword*` or `http://example.com/application1/AlsoNotKeyword/*`

What is the right approach for that?
I played around with some  mod_rewrite rules, it seems they don’t take affect or break everything (in httpd.conf). I was also reading that we should not use   mod_rewrite rules inside of location tag (can't find the reference now).
What else can I do?

Edit: So finally I found my error (somehow wrong syntax which not prevented the server from starting (like usual).

So I could:
in httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule "(.*)/application1/MagicKeyword/(.*)$" "https://www.example.org" [NC,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

or in the Location tag add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "(.*)/MagicKeyword/(.*)$" "https://www.example.org" [NC,L,R=301]
```

Why should I prefer one over the other?
Is there anything to concern about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two other options you can consider. You can use the order of location tags:

```
<Location /application1/MagicKeyword>
    WebLogicHost otherhost
</Location> 
<Location /application1>
    WebLogicHost 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

You can tell WebLogic to exclude a path (see https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/PLGWL/plugin_params.htm#PLGWL473):

```
<Location /application1>
    WebLogicHost 127.0.0.1
    WLExcludePathOrMimeType /application1/MagicKeyword
</Location> 
<Location /application1>
    WebLogicHost otherhost
</Location>
```

Comment: Even more options ... is there any reason why choosing one over the other?

Comment: I'd take the first option, as this is generally the way to handle location overlap in Apache.